# clang-format without line wrapping (for existing code)

Tags: c++, git, code-formatting, clang-format, legacy-code

I really like automatic formatting, not only because it reduces time spent manually formatting code, but especially because it reduces time spent on pointless formatting discussions during code review. Unfortunately, there is often strong resistance to formatting existing code, particularly on projects where the style guide recommends trying to guess/match the bespoke style of every file you edit.

For most projects, agreeing on a style to use going forward and using `git-clang-format` is probably good enough. Unfortunately, `git-clang-format`  does not do very well on code that uses a mix of spaces, width 8 hard tabs, and width 4 hard tabs.

I think *nobody* is fond of the mixed indentation, so if we could apply clang formatting in a way that doesn't show up in `git diff -w` or `git blame -w` it might be enough to overcome a lot of the objection to formatting existing code. We could then gradually converge on fully formatted code via `git-clang-format` on subsequent changes.

Worst case, I might be able to configure GNU `indent` or `astyle` to indent in a way that is consistent with the chosen `.clang-format`, but that seems like it would be more error-prone.

Is there a way to run `clang-format` on C++ code so that it only makes whitespace changes, without changing line wrapping? If not, what is the best way to achieve the same with other tools?

Comment: This seems to be a git question, and not really a c++ or clang-format question.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Hopefully that's clearer.